# How can I use Java code to set up a one-line multi-column label for the Bartender template?

Tags: java, activex

I am using com to call ActiveX to enable Java to print labels using Bartender. If the label paper to be printed is single-column, then the printing effect is normal. However, if the template page is set to multi-column mode with one row and two or more columns in the Bartender software, the actual effect of the following code is that only the left label has content and the right label has no content. How can I modify the code to make both the left and right labels have data?

```
//open Templete
                btFormat = Dispatch.call(btFormats,"Open",filePatch,false,"").toDispatch();
                Dispatch printSetup = Dispatch.get(btFormat,"PrintSetup").toDispatch();
                Dispatch.put(printSetup,"Printer","TSC TE244");
                    int size=printDatas.size();
                    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                        Map<String,String>printMap=printDatas.get(i);
                        if(printMap!=null){
                            for(Map.Entry<String,String>entry:printMap.entrySet()){

                                try{
                                    //Replace variables in templates
                                    Dispatch.call(btFormat,"SetNamedSubStringValue",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
                                }catch (Exception e){

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Dispatch.call(btFormat,"PrintOut",false,false);
```

Actual printing

I tried to set the parameter IdenticalCopiesOfLabel to 2, and it can print two columns, but the content of the two columns is the same, which does not meet the expected effect. In addition, I also tried to set the parameter NumberSerializedLabels , but the printed content is still a single column